# Why is it called a Four-Poster Bed, and not a Four-Post Bed

Tags: etymology

It seems that every reference I can find refers to the columns of a four-poster bed as 'posts', so why is it called a four-poster bed?

I've found [some](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tester) [references](https://grimsdyke.com/four-poster-bed/) that indicate that it was called a four-post bed in the 14th and 15th centuries, but nothing describing the change over time or where it came from.

A friend posited:

> I assume it came from the way people talk. “That’s a four poster there”

But I would just like some more information regarding that. Is it just a change in the way people talk? Or maybe how they write?

Comment: Please see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/er) definition of **er**. *4. suffix. You add -er to nouns to form nouns or adjectives which refer to things with a particular characteristic or feature; for example a 'three-wheeler' is a vehicle with three wheels.* So a four-poster bed has four corner posts.

Comment: It's because it calls for a poster girl. [joke]

Comment: Sometimes the suffix -ed is added.  A three-legged stool. for example.

Comment: I would argue that it's actually called a "four poster" not a "four poster bed". A "four poster bed" is the same type of redundancy as an "ATM machine" (where the M is already an abbreviation for "machine") Similarly with the other examples in the answers like "a six wheeler" not "a six wheeler truck" etc.

Comment: It's common to use an adjective as a noun when the adjective provides enough information to avoid ambiguity. I understand this is called "ellipsis of noun phrases". Example: "The rich" means "the rich people".

Comment: [Sugar Ray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cqU1pFRqYE) begs to differ...

Comment: Sometimes the *-er* is applied directly to the number.  A [*fourteener*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteener) is a mountain that is at least 14,000 feet in elevation, a [*fifty-niner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-Niner) was a participant in the Gold Rush of 1859, and *fiver* and *tenner* are both sometimes used for paper currency in denominations of 5 or 10 (pounds or dollars).

Comment: @alephzero, thank you, that is a good point to make and clarifies it some more.

Comment: @Ben, ah, that's a good thing to know. I had not heard of that, but it is completely obvious now. That gives a concrete example to why this works this way.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, yes, that's what my friend said 

Comment: @CanadianYankee: tons of fabulous examples, exactly what I needed. I live in Colorado, how could I not think of fourteener!!!???

Comment: I'm guessing that it became "four poster" following the usual pattern, but at some later stage the noun "bed" got added back on.  But I don't have any evidence (SOED just has a sub-entry under __four__ for "__four-poster (bed)__", with no etymology of its own).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a common (though not necessary) way to refer to any object with multiples of a given component.

For instance a [three wheeler vehicle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-wheeler) which can be a car, bike (strange in itself as 'bike' is short for 'bicycle' or 'two wheels'), handcart or anything else with a tricycle wheel arrangement.

Also a sailing ship with three masts can be called a [three master](https://www.timmersgems.com/en/schip-confection--three-master-from-the-18th-century.html)

A ['hackney carriage' with four wheels](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/d=four-wheeler)  was called a 'four wheeler'. They are often mentioned in the Sherlock Homes books.

A [truck with six wheels](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/six-wheeler) (and sometimes one with ten wheels on three axles) is also called a 'six wheeler'. This is also extended to 'eight wheeler', 'ten wheeler' (another name for a six wheeler with twin wheels on the rear axles) and so on.

Those are just a few of the common names for things that are named in the same way as 'four poster' beds so you see it's quite old: at least Victorian, Conan Doyle was writing contemporary fiction in  contemporary language when he wrote the Sherlock Holmes books.

Comment: Hm. I guess that kind of makes sense, but I can't think of any examples other than four poster and 18 wheeler (things with wheels seem to get this treatment). Like what about windows with multiple panes. We don't call them 4 paner windows, right? Some more examples would be helpful, though this seems like the answer I was looking for.

Comment: my wife gave me some examples that seem _different_ than this? For example, a 4 legged animal. Why is it legged and not legger then? What about a three headed dragon? or like a 3 tiered cake, 10 story building. Guess I'm just confused as to why `-er` seems to only be used for like, ~2~ 3 (forgot about three master) things in the whole english language.

Comment: We do talk about a two-hander, three-hander, referring to the number of players in a game. But as always, the answer to "why does X language not have Y feature" is almost always "because that's the way it is". Languages are what they are, not what somebody with a tidy mind thinks they ought to be.

Comment: Yes of course @ColinFine, I understand that, just seems weird there's so limited use.

Comment: @snowe2010 - This is used with "seat" as well - a sofa can be a "three seater" or a car can be a "five seater".

Comment: @CanadianYankee Ah of course! I can't believe I didn't think of that. So it _is_ more common, just a small thing that I've never noticed.

Seems very car oriented :D

Comment: @snowe2010 - following your original logic indeed a 4 legged animal should simply be a "4 leg animal". So I'm not sure this is too different after all, just another instance of a kind of arbitrary letter adding with a different suffix ('ed' instead of 'er' in this case).

Comment: Yes, you explain the formation of the word "four-poster", which is a *noun*, but how come people also use it as an attributive adjective, as in "four-poster bed"? That's what the OP asked. In Britain we call 2-deck buses "double-deckers" or, sometimes, "double-decker buses". Such "-er" forms are not always used to modify nouns.

Comment: Also "double-header" is a fairly common usage isn't it? Isn't "all-nighter" a similar construction?

Comment: @snowe2010 Why sometimes -ed and sometimes -er? Interesting question, why don't you ask it as a new question?

Comment: @RosieF "Four-poster" is an adjective like "rich" and "poor", but we still say "The rich" and "the poor" meaning "the rich people" and "the poor people". This is called ellipsis of noun phrases.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee: Though with cars, it's most often a "two seater" (for sports cars), since they're by default assumed to be 4-5 passenger vehicles.  See e.g. P.G. Wodehouse and Bertie Wooster's "old two-seater".

Comment: @RosieF Don't forget the 'double-decker sandwich' as well leading to the "Cadbury's Double Decker" chocolate bar.

Comment: @Ben  Colin implies an interesting point. We have a two-hander and two-handed and they seem different. Not sure what the rule is there.

Comment: @RosieF, I actually didn't realize there was a difference . Thinking of it in terms of something like `double-decker` or `double-header` or `the rich` really cemented it in as a completely separate construct, and I was _incorrectly_ using it like `four-poster bed`, which now seems redundant!

Comment: Further to BoldBen's excellent Answer, I think both that the syntax here is more important than in many another English sentence and that there's a cross-Atlantic element here. 

Yes, a sailing ship with three masts is often called a three-master; a carriage with four wheels a four-wheeler.

I'm suggesting that a description of a vehicle with three wheels will necessarily follow that style, so the usage "(That is a) three-wheeler vehicle" will be insignificant vanishingly rare compared to the apparently very similar "(That vehicle is) a three-wheeler".

More…

Comment: Further… I suspect this bridges the Atlantic with forms more like "racing car" or "sailing boat" here in the UK and "race car" or "sail boat" in the USA.

Comment: The animal variant I believe would be `four-legger`. I kind of like that!

Answer (score 9):

BoldBen's answer is indeed correct, but I thought there was a little more to add. When the context is clear, nouns formed in this way usually stand on their own. You hear "two-seater" more often than "two-seater car," or "six-shooter" rather than "six-shooter gun." Very often these terms are coined in exactly these situations where the context is clear. Then, when it becomes unclear, the noun indicating the category gets added.

Answer (score 7):

Referring to a noun that has a specific characteristic, there are probably hundreds of examples like runner, sleeper, hunter, worker, steamer, driver, revolver, etc. etc.

For those that include a numeric component there are fewer, but include, off the top of my head:

- 6 footer (someone/something who is six feet tall),
- 6 pounder (common cannon size, firing a 6 pound projectile - also available in other calibres),
- 6 shooter (gun with 6 bullets),
- 5 miler (race of 5 miles).

Comment: As per [Rosie F's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564422/why-is-it-called-a-four-poster-bed-and-not-a-four-post-bed#comment1397162_564424) these are all nouns ending in '-er', whereas the OP is asking about this construct used as an adjective. With "three-legged dog" and "one-armed man" the adjective form uses "-ed", not "-er", so why the difference?

Comment: "6 pounder" is also an adjective in "6 pounder gun", e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QF_6-pounder_Hotchkiss. Similarly "a four poster" can be a noun, with "bed" implicit.

Comment: @user7761803 - There is a simple answer to this but it needs to be a separate question.

Comment: @user7761803 I would argue that it is not an adjective, or maybe that English frequently has constructions which use nouns "as an adjective" in your sense. Compare "cantaloupe melon", "red velvet cake", "Lufthansa plane" - we don't say "Lufthansian plane", we chain a first noun denoting the kind, then the general noun. I don't know if this construction has a specific name among linguists, but I think it is the one that applies to "four poster", used with or without "bed" afterwards.

Comment: @user7761803 I think you could analyze them as attributive nouns, like "face mask" or "woman doctor."

Answer (score 0):

I can certainly agree that one can say "a 4-poster" when describing a bed, but there is no way that it is proper English to say "a 4-poster bed". If you're going to add the word "bed" in your description, then you must say "a 4-***post*** bed". "A 4-poster bed" makes it sound like there are 4 posters (as in a promo or show bill) on the bed, and not 4 wooden posts.

Comment: Following that logic, wouldn't describing the bed as being "a 4-poster" also mean that it has 4 posters? Why would adding "bed" at the end change that?